# merge two arrays by matching on different columns where arrays are of unequal length unequal length

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to merge two arrays on columns with similar data

I can get this to work if both arrays have the same length dimension, but how can I generalize my function to work if arrays have different lengths?

where either arrA or arrB could have the greater length

Thank you

what I get

```
[ [ 'age', 'AAA', 'name' ],
  [ 25, 'aaa', 'Alice' ],
  [ 30, 'bbb', 'Bob' ] ]
```

what I want

```
[
  [ 'age', 'AAA', 'name' ],
  [ 25, 'aaa', 'Alice' ],
  [ 30, 'bbb', 'Bob' ],
  [ 60, 'zzz', '' ] 
]
```

```js
function mergeRowsLOOP_n() {
  const arrB = [
    ["id", "name"],
    [1, "Alice"],
    [2, "Bob"],
  ];

  const arrA = [
    ["age", "ID", "AAA"],
    [25, 1, "aaa"],
    [30, 2, "bbb"],
    [60, 5, "zzz"]
  ];

  let X = mergeRowsLOOP(arrA, arrB, "ID", "id");
  console.log(X)
}

//a= array1, b=array2
//aKey = Header for Matching of arra1, bKey = Header for Matching of arra2
//bColumns indices of postback columns of array2; bColumns=[] to postback ALL array2 columns
function mergeRowsLOOP(a, b, aKey, bKey, bColumns = []) {

  const bIdx = b[0].findIndex(s => s.toLowerCase() === bKey.toLowerCase());
  bColumns = (bColumns.length === 0) ? b : getColumns(b, [bIdx, ...bColumns]);

  const aIdx = a[0].findIndex(s => s.toLowerCase() === aKey.toLowerCase()),
    bColumnsIdx = bColumns[0].findIndex(s => s.toLowerCase() === bKey.toLowerCase()),
    mergedArray = [];
  console.log(bColumnsIdx)
  for (let rowA of a) {
    for (let rowB of bColumns) {
      if (rowA[aIdx].toString().toLowerCase() === rowB[bColumnsIdx].toString().toLowerCase()) {
        rowA = spliceNthPos(rowA, aIdx);
        rowB = spliceNthPos(rowB, bColumnsIdx);
        mergedArray.push(rowA.concat(rowB, ));
      }
    }
  };

  return mergedArray;
}

function spliceNthPos(row, n) {
  let i = row.length;
  while (i--) {
    i === n && row.splice(i, 1);
  }
  return row;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to achieve the following conversion.

  - From

    ```
      const arrB = [
        ["id", "name"],
        [1, "Alice"],
        [2, "Bob"],
      ];

      const arrA = [
        ["age", "ID", "AAA"],
        [25, 1, "aaa"],
        [30, 2, "bbb"],
        [60, 5, "zzz"]
      ];
    ```
  - To

    ```
      [
        [ 'age', 'AAA', 'name' ],
        [ 25, 'aaa', 'Alice' ],
        [ 30, 'bbb', 'Bob' ],
        [ 60, 'zzz', '' ] 
      ]
    ```

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
const arrB = [
  ["id", "name"],
  [1, "Alice"],
  [2, "Bob"],
];

const arrA = [
  ["age", "ID", "AAA"],
  [25, 1, "aaa"],
  [30, 2, "bbb"],
  [60, 5, "zzz"]
];

const [[arrBhead, ...arrBvalues], [arrAhead, ...arrAvalues]] = [arrB, arrA];
const [arrBIdIdx, arrAIdIdx] = [arrBhead, arrAhead].map(a => a.findIndex(e => e.toLowerCase() == "id"));
const [arrBObj, arrAObj] = [[arrBvalues, arrBIdIdx], [arrAvalues, arrAIdIdx]].map(([a, b]) => new Map(a.map(e => [e.splice(b, 1)[0], e])));
const temp = Array(arrBhead.length - 1).fill("");
const newHead = [[arrAhead, arrAIdIdx], [arrBhead, arrBIdIdx]].flatMap(([a, b]) => (a.splice(b, 1), a));
const res = [newHead, ...[...arrAObj].map(([k, v]) => [...v, ...(arrBObj.has(k) ? arrBObj.get(k) : temp)])];

console.log(res);
```

When the processes of `arrB` and `arrA` are separeted, it becomes as follows.

```js
const arrB = [
  ["id", "name"],
  [1, "Alice"],
  [2, "Bob"],
];

const arrA = [
  ["age", "ID", "AAA"],
  [25, 1, "aaa"],
  [30, 2, "bbb"],
  [60, 5, "zzz"]
];

// About arrB
const [arrBhead, ...arrBvalues] = arrB;
const arrBIdIdx = arrBhead.findIndex(e => e.toLowerCase() == "id");
const arrBObj = new Map(arrBvalues.map(e => [e.splice(arrBIdIdx, 1)[0], e]));

// About arrA
const [arrAhead, ...arrAvalues] = arrA;
const arrAIdIdx = arrAhead.findIndex(e => e.toLowerCase() == "id");
const arrAObj = new Map(arrAvalues.map(e => [e.splice(arrAIdIdx, 1)[0], e]));

// Merge
const temp = Array(arrBhead.length - 1).fill("");
const newHead = [[arrAhead, arrAIdIdx], [arrBhead, arrBIdIdx]].flatMap(([a, b]) => (a.splice(b, 1), a));
const res = [newHead, ...[...arrAObj].map(([k, v]) => [...v, ...(arrBObj.has(k) ? arrBObj.get(k) : temp)])];

console.log(res);
```

When this script is run, the following result is obtained.

```
[
  ["age","AAA","name"],
  [25,"aaa","Alice"],
  [30,"bbb","Bob"],
  [60,"zzz",""]
]
```

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Comment: Yes, that is what I needed, and I can follow about 90% of it. Thank you

Comment: Also, thank you for splitting them out this really helps in understanding the first function

Answer (score 2):

An approach with an object and an array for empty columns.

```js
const
    mergeBy = tables => {
        const
            SPACER = '',
            empty = [],
            head = [],
            rows = {};
            
        tables.forEach(([table, key]) => {
            const
                index = table[0].indexOf(key);
                    
            table.forEach(({ [index]: key, ...row }, i) => {
                if (i) (rows[key] ??= [...empty]).push(...Object.values(row));
                else head.push(...Object.values(row));
            });
            empty.push(...Array(table[0].length - 1).fill(SPACER));
        });

        return [head, ...Object.values(rows)].map(a => {
            while (a.length < empty.length) a.push(SPACER);
            return a;
        });
    },
    arrB = [["id", "name"], [1, "Alice"], [2, "Bob"], [4, 'Jane']],
    arrA = [["age", "ID", "AAA"], [25, 1, "aaa"], [30, 2, "bbb"], [60, 5, "zzz"]],
    result = mergeBy([[arrA, "ID"], [arrB, "id"]]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Another approach for keeping the first key column or not.

```js
const
    mergeBy = (tables, keepFirstKey = false) => {
        const
            SPACER = '',
            empty = [],
            head = [],
            rows = {};
            
        tables.forEach(([table, key], j) => {
            const
                index = table[0].indexOf(key),
                withKey = (row, i) => {
                    const key = row[index];
                    if (i) (rows[key] ??= [...empty]).push(...row);
                    else head.push(...row);
                },
                withoutKey = ({ [index]: key, ...row }, i) => {
                    if (i) (rows[key] ??= [...empty]).push(...Object.values(row));
                    else head.push(...Object.values(row));
                },
                takeKey = !j && keepFirstKey;
                
            table.forEach(takeKey ? withKey : withoutKey);
            empty.push(...Array(table[0].length - !takeKey).fill(SPACER));
        });

        return [head, ...Object.values(rows)].map(a => {
            while (a.length < empty.length) a.push(SPACER);
            return a;
        });
    },
    arrB = [["id", "name"], [1, "Alice"], [2, "Bob"], [4, 'Jane']],
    arrA = [["age", "ID", "AAA"], [25, 1, "aaa"], [30, 2, "bbb"], [60, 5, "zzz"]];

console.log(mergeBy([[arrA, "ID"], [arrB, "id"]]));
console.log(mergeBy([[arrA, "ID"], [arrB, "id"]], true));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Nina, thank you. I am getting an `unexpected Token at line 15`  when trying to save. Line 15 is this `if (i) (rows[key] ??= [...empty]).push(...Object.values(row));`  I can not figure out what App Script editor is objecting to

Comment: you could replace in `rows[key] ??= [...empty]` the [logical nullish assignment `??=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) with `rows[key] = rows[key] || [...empty]`

Comment: Thank you. This works great when Arrays are of equal length but often Arrays are of different lengths.

Comment: it works for any lengths.

Comment: Opps, sorry my Bad

Comment: Nina, I realize that I often need to Keep the matching column for the first array in mergeby. in this case `ID` is it possible to add this feature? I have been trying but can not get it. Thank you

Comment: which one do you want to keep? and where?

Comment: I need to keep the matching column in the first array in mergeby (in the above example) `[arrA, "ID"]` in whatever position it was originally in

Comment: Nina, I figured this out. Thank you again

Comment: @NinaScholz, the Question is tagged with google-apps-script , which does not currently support the nullish coalescing assignment operator. It's excellent Javascript though :).